# Is it correct to use get_by_key_name to extract just one field from GAE datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is what I do:

```
class Person(db.Model):  
  first_name = db.StringProperty()
  last_name = db.StringProperty()
  middle_name = db.StringProperty()
  ...
  photo = db.BlobProperty()

person = Person.get_by_key_name(person_key_name)
if person == None or not person.photo:
  self.response.set_status(404, 'Not Found')
  return      
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
self.response.out.write(person.photo)
```

Shouldn't I use `SELECT` with just one field (`photo`) instead of `get_by_key_name`?

Comment: It looks right. You could also do `photo = Person.get_by_id(long(id)).photo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

GQL is not SQL. There is no way of doing a SELECT query with "just one field" - you can *only* do either `SELECT *` or `SELECT __key__`.